# Questions regarding rubbing catfur on glass

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

I have certain questions regarding the electrostatic charge developed by this rubbing effects:

1-what is the threshold for electrostatic charges by this process?

2-can we define potential energy associated to the system, post rubbing?

3-If we can define Potential, then whats the efficiency of this process of changing Kinetic energy to potential energy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why two objects get charged by rubbing?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/why-two-objects-get-charged-by-rubbing)

Comment: See also [How does rubbing cause the transfer of electrons from one object to the other?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44486/how-does-rubbing-cause-the-transfer-of-electrons-from-one-object-to-the-other)

Comment: Well, my fourth point may have a possible duplicate, but about the rest? I would edit the question and remove the fourth one...